# Why the matching results are different between for example, r'\b(?:(can)|(could))\b' and r'(\bcan\b)|(\bcould\b)'?

Tags: python, regex

`r'\b(?:(can)|(could))\b'` is much faster than `r'(\bcan\b)|(\bcould\b)'`. This makes sense, since the first pattern starts to look from word boundaries and is more efficient. What puzzles me is that the two patterns generate slightly different results with `re.findall`, for my keyword lists and documents. Changing the code makes the matching much faster, but I'm not able to replicate my earlier results.

These two patterns appear to be equivalent to me except for the difference in efficiency. Am I missing something?

My pattern is as follows, and can be found [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/5eEd22/1)  The inputs are too large to be posted. They are txt files containing tens of thousands of words.

```
\b(?:(Anti-takeover (?:provisions|provision))|(Bank debt[s]?)|(Capital 
(?:expenditure|expenditures))|(Capital (?:lease|leases))|(Chapter 11)| 
(Chapter 7)|(Chapter 9)|(Collateral[s]?)|(Concentrated ownership[s]?)| 
(Covenant|covenants)|(Credit (?:facility|facilities))|(Credit rating[s]?)| 
(Credit risk[s]?)|(Debt burden[s]?)|(Decline in stock price[s]?)| 
(Default[s]?|defaulted)|(Defined Benefit[s]?)|(Dilution[s]?)|(Dividend[s]?)| 
(Downgrade[s]?)|(Family)|(Financial condition[s]?)|(Financing cost[s]?)| 
(Funded status)|(Illiquid market[s]?)|(Improvements)|(Indebtedness)|(Insider 
sales)|(Investment[s]? in equipment)|(Investment[s]? in plant[s]?)|(Lease 
(?:commitment|commitments))|(lease|leases|leasing)|(Leverage[s]?)| 
(Leveraged (?:lease|leases))|(Limited trading)|(Liquidity|Liquidities)| 
(Loan[s]?)|(Locked-in (?:lease|leases))|(Mandatory contribution[s]?)| 
(Maturity|maturities)|(Negative operating cash flow[s]?)|(New financing)|(? 
-i:O.P.E.B.)|(Obligations)|(?-i:OPEB)|(Operating losses)|(Penny stock[s]?)| 
(Postretirement[s]?)|(Rating[s]?)|(Refinance)|(Refinancing)|(Reinsurance)| 
(Renegotiation[s]?)|(Reorganization[s]?)|(Reserves)|(Revolver[s]?)|(Sale 
of productive assets)|(Stock market listing)|(Stock price 
(?:volatility|volatilities))|(Stock price drop[s]?)|(Underfunded 
 pensions)|(Underwriting)|(Volatility of operating results)|(Volatility of 
 revenues)|(Volatility of sales)|(Working capital[s]?))\b
```

I understand that the regex is not elegant. It was generated from a list of keywords. Some keywords are in mixed forms such as "provisions|provision". "provision[s]?" or simply "provisions?" would be better. I made some changes, but not all. 
Originally it was generated by:

```
re_fin = '|'.join(r'((?-i:\b{}\b))'.format(k) if k.upper() == k else 
        r'(\b{}\b)'.format(k) for k in keywords])
```

I found it very slow, and changed it to the following (to show all the steps):

```
  patterns = [r"(?-i:{})".format(k) if k.upper() == k else r"({})".format(k) 
            for k in keywords]
  patterns = "|".join(patterns)
  patterns = r"\b(?:{})\b".format(patterns)
```

Comment: Please lead us to those different results by including them in the question.

Comment: `but I'm able to replicate...` do you mean *unable*?

Comment: Can you upload your regex, your input and your expected output? Please share the regex via https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, it is because of the grouping issue.

patterns = [r"(?-i:{})".format(k) if k.upper() == k else r"({})".format(k) 
            for k in keywords]

The all-CAP keywords were not grouped, so were not captured by re.findall. (?-i:{}) should have been (?-i:({}))